# Badge to encourage highly upvoted answers that are complete without needing edits

Tags: discussion, answers, badge-request

We all know of the [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) problem. People answer fast, often with very little content to get early upvotes.

Why not introduce a badge that encourages complete answers?

We could remove the [Enlightened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened) badge since it encourages to answer first and improve later (why do we even have that badge) and introduce a new badge that is of some kind the opposite: It encourages posting an answer when it is complete.

A possible name would be "Spot-on match". It would be awareded if an answer reaches a score of 10 without being edited.

The only problem I see is that some users might not fix minor errors in their answer to get the badge.

Comment: Some FGITW answers don't appear to have been editing because they were edited in the first 5 minutes.

Comment: Yep, but they are edited. I am not sure if the system knows that.

Comment: Is your proposed badge can be rewarded just once or for every user that answered a question with score of 10+ without being edited?

Comment: For every answer with score of 10+ and not edited. Just like the Enlightend badge.

Comment: @juergend, `Enlightened` also requires your answer to be accepted.

Comment: Why would we remove the Enlightened badge? It doesn’t encourage anything that reputation doesn’t.

Comment: Personally, I don't see FGIW as a huge problem, or necessarily a problem at all. I love the fact that I can post a question on SO and sometimes get an answer in less than a minute. That's awesome.

Answer (score 14):

Every answer has room for improvement.  I don't want to incentivize letting answers sit in an incomplete, or worse in an actively incorrect state until they reach 10 votes.

Comment: That is a very good point. We should not 'punish' legitimate edits just because of FGITW posts.